# Using python psutil on a shared webhost

Tags: python, web-hosting, webfaction

I want to use python psutil to create my own panel that I will use to administer my app op webfaction. If I use functions like

```
psutil.network_io_counters()
```

or

```
psutil.disk_usage()
```

will this be specific to the the whole of webfaction servers or will it be specific to my app only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`psutil` will return data only for the system in which is running on.